# How Can I Change The Background Of My Site When A Key Is Pressed?

Tags: html, keyboard, keypress

I'm Making A Game In Html, And I Need To Link To Another Page When A Key Is Pressed.

I've Tried href And Some Other Things.
My Code Is:

```
<element onkeypress="Gamestart()"> 
<script>
function Gamestart() {
<a href="Part_Two.html">Play</a>
}
</script>
```

Html Never Really Gives People Error Messages, So I Have No Error Messages, But My Code Does Not Work.

Answer (score 0):

You have HTML inside your Javascript function which makes no sense. You would be better using the anchor tag `<a>` with an `onclick` attribute to trigger a JavaScript function.

You can use the JavaScript  `window.open()` to open a new page.

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Click here</a>

<script>
function myFunction {
    window.open("https://your-url-here.com/page");
}
</script>
```

You can do whatever you want in this function, including changing an image like you mention in the title.